# Maruti Alto Starting Problem

Tags: starting

i have hired a Mechanic and he asked me to replace few accessories, still the car did not start it just give crank and goes off thereof

Comment: Did you check the fuse?

Comment: ya i have checked and it was replaced with new

Comment: What parts did the mechanic have you replace?